# How to get full html content of specific url?

Tags: php, dom

I used several method to get html content of aptoide.com in php.

1) `file_get_contents();`

2) `readfile();`

3) curl as php function

```
function get_dataa($url) {
   $ch = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/4.0; Microsoft Windows) KHTML/4.0.80 (like Gecko)");
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   return $data;
}
```

4)PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url="http://aptoide.com";
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

But all of them give empty output for aptoide.com
Is there a way to get full html content of that url ?

Comment: Simple `echo file_get_contents('http://www.aptoide.com/');` is working perfectly for me. Your problem is probably something else. Do you have this problem with other URLs? Maybe `aptoide.com` has blocked your IP.

Comment: is there a way to change my ip in curl request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo file_get_contents('http://www.aptoide.com/');` works fine for me.

So it's possible that `aptoide.com` has been blocked you. If you want to change your IP (as you said in comment) you have to use this:

```
$url = 'http://aptoide.com.com/';
$proxy = '127.0.0.1:9095'; // Your proxy
// $proxyauth = 'user:password'; // Proxy authentication if required

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

Answer (score 0):

use your curl get_dataa function with this line added:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

because that page is redirecting to www.aptide.com
full function:

```
function get_dataa($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/4.0; Microsoft Windows) KHTML/4.0.80 (like Gecko)");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Not worked. it seems they have blocked curl or using some methods